# Is it possible to create a Windows 7 System Image Backup while booted from a Win7 Install Disk / Repair Tools?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup

My Win7 system has developed a boot loop, and none of the things I've tried has been able to fix it.  `chkdsk` says the disk is OK, and `sfc` says no problems found.  However, it still enters System Repair every boot, and the repair fails with `CorruptedVolume`.

Is there some way to create a System Image backup from the disk while booted from a Win7 installation CD (under the System Recovery tools, for example)?  Any other way to get the user, application & update information from the old disk onto a fresh Win7 installation on a new disk?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. While your question is interesting, it sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445). Consider describing your problem without constraining answers to a specific solution, and let others apply their knowledge to help you get thinks working again.

Comment: It would seem easier to download a Windows 7 ISO from MS and reinstall. Do image the disk beforehand, though, should there be a problem. Follow directions at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7

Comment: I have an official Win7 CD, so I can do a fresh install any time.  However, the last time I did, it took most of a day to install all the updates, and that's before I find & install the applications and copy over all the user data.  So I'd like to make the kind of backup that the install process will accept, and do all that automagically.  The current disk (which won't boot) still has all the applications and data.  I expect the boot-loop is just an EFI partition bug, but I don't know enough about EFI (and Windows booting generally) to find it and fix it.